# Is this valid syntax in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-usememo

I am working on a React project and in there I have to initialize a socket once the component's been mounted. For that I am using this syntax and I want to know whether or not it is valid.

```js
function Component() {
    const socket = useMemo(() => {
        return io('http://localhost:3001')
    },[socket]);

    return (
        <h1>Component</h1>
    )
}
```

This way, my project and the sockets are working just fine but I want to know the conventional way to achieve the same. I used the same syntax in another React project and it gave me a "Reference Error" for the `socket` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a dependency array to your `useMemo`, otherwise it'll be triggered at each render. After that, yes it's a valid syntax :)

```
const socket = useMemo(() => {
    return io('http://localhost:3001')
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I kinda put the wrong code ! I have updated the question you can now take a look at it. Again sorry for such a silly mistake.

I am concerned about putting the same variable as a dependency in useMemo() hook.

Comment: Ok, so, why would you do that? Have you a concrete case for this? ;) The dependency array should countains only variables which ned to retriger a useEffect when they change. So I don't see why you would say "i'm setting a variable that should be recalculated when it changes itself" :)

Comment: oh ! okay ! Actually I did know the meaning of dependencies and the meaning of passing the same variable as a dependency but the last quote of yours changed everything. That is a great Explanation. Thanks a lot.